# is there a less cluttered version of the Swype keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, swype

I am new to Android.  I really like the Swype keyboard but wish I could remove certain keys on the bottom row (e.g. SYM, the "EN" language button, etc) so that the keyboard is less cluttered.

Is this possible?  Are their any Swype equivalent keyboards that aren't as compact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try [FlexT9](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nuance.flext9.input&feature=search_result). It's a bit pricey, but has the same functionality as Swype, with some great added features (Dragon speech support and trace input) and a better layout (in my opinion, let me know what you think of it ;) ).

Here's a screenshot from the app page:
[image]